# Need a proofreading why all the units are satisfied $a^2-2b^2 =\pm1$ for $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, proof-verification

All the units are satisfied Pell's equation $a^2-2b^2=\pm1$  for $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, $a,b\in\mathbf{Z}$.

Here is my proof:

Let $a+b\sqrt{2}$ be a unit $\in\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. This implies
$$(a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2})=1, c+d\sqrt{2}\in\mathbf{Z}\sqrt{2}$$
$$\implies \mathrm{norm}((a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2}))=1$$
$$\implies \mathrm{norm}(a+b\sqrt{2})\cdot \mathrm{norm}(c+d\sqrt{2})=1$$
$$\implies (a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2})(c-d\sqrt{2})=1$$
$$\implies (a^2-2b^2)(c^2-2d^2)=1$$
$$\implies \left[ a^2-2b^2=1\text{ and } {c}^2-2{d}^2=1\right]\text{ or } \left[ a^2-2{b}^2=-1\text{ and }{c}^2-2{d}^2=-1\right]$$
$$\implies {a}^2-2{b}^2=\pm1$$

Comment: What have you tried? Why is the function $a + b\sqrt{2} \mapsto a^2 - 2b^2$ important?

Comment: $$\text{We knew }(\textbf{a+b}\sqrt{2})(\textbf{a-b}\sqrt{2})=\textbf{a}^2-2\textbf{b}^2\quad \text{but our assumption of a unit is conjugation form}$$

Comment: (Sorry, didn't see the edit). Yep. Are you familiar with the norm function?

Comment: Yep, $$nom(\alpha\beta)=norm(\alpha)norm(\beta)$$

Comment: (Have you proved that / do you get to assume that?) Also, what's your definition of unit?

Comment: $(\textbf{a+b}\sqrt{2})(\textbf{c+d}\sqrt{2})=1$

Comment: Alright. If $\alpha$ is a unit, what might you want to plug in for $\beta$?

Comment: $\beta=(\textbf{c+d}\sqrt{2})$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11788/discussion-between-henry-swanson-and-bsdshell)

Comment: Wait, can you join chat? I'm not sure if being invited overrules reputation

Comment: Anyways: Put all of it together, you have $\alpha \beta = 1$ and a statement about norms.

Comment: sorry, I can't join the chat, not sure why,

Comment: I will write the full proof and you can check it out.

Comment: (I've gotta sleep for now, but post anyways, someone else can check for you)