# Need a proof to show all the units are satisfied $\mathbf{Z}\sqrt{2}$ is the all the integer solution in Pell equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

We know the integer solutions of Pell's equation $$a^2-2b^2=\pm1$$ correspond to the units of $\textbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. How can we prove this?

Comment: I've edited your post for grammar and formatting. Please check to see that I didn't change the meaning.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590775/need-a-proofreading-why-all-the-units-are-satisfied-a2-2b2-pm1-for-mathb?rq=1.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you mean if $(a,b)$ is a solution of Pell's equation then $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}\sqrt{2}$. This directly follows from the fact$$(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})=\pm 1$$

Comment: Yes, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590775/need-a-proofreading-why-all-the-units-are-satisfied-a2-2b2-pm1-for-mathb?rq=1.